# ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error

Tags: oracle

I'm getting this error when performing an import using data pump in Oracle 11g.

```
ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -1031
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in DISPATCH
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Any idea how I find out what the exact privilege it is that is missing?

Comment: Might be helpful to show your impdp command and more of the log. But [possible cross-site duplicate](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/40074/847).

Answer (score 1):

check your privilege in tab Users > your schema > Alter > Setting System Privileges (I made Grant All and Admin All) it's work on my case.